# Unknowns in basic vectors

Tags: vectors

Haven't touched vectors for years and need some help with the following

Given $ u = 3i + 2j$ and $ v = 2i + \lambda j$, find values for $\lambda$ such that 
a) the angle between $ u$ and $ v$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ 
b) the length of projection of $u$ on $v$ is 2 units.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: give it a try first? try to read up on how to compute angle and length?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- a) $(u,v)=||u||||v||\cos\theta$
- b) If $w$ is the projection of $u$ on $v$ then $w=\rho v$ for some scalar $\rho$ and $(u-w)\bot v$ (express this by means of inproduct).